# How should I deal with an unused water line that's dripping?

Tags: refrigerator

For some reason an old refrigerator water line that has not been used for months started leaking. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Where does the other end go?

Comment: There should be a valve at the other end of that line. Find the valve and take a photo for us. It could be the valve has started to fail.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a 1/4" copper tube with a kink in it. The kink may or may not be what's been holding the water back all this time.

A combination of fittings could be found to cap that tube. A 1/4" compression to male pipe thread adapter followed by a female threaded cap could get the job done, for example. It would be recommended to cut the tube upstream of the kink, though, because the tube is weakened at the kink and is more susceptible to failing.

The better approach is as Alaska Man wrote in a comment: there should be a valve at the other end of this tube. Likely locations for the valve include under the kitchen sink or somewhere near the water heater. The valve may need to be closed more tightly, repaired, or removed. If you can located the valve, or at least candidate(s) that might be the valve, post pictures of it/them and we may be able to advise further.

Comment: or you could remove the tube from the valve and thread on a cap there.

Comment: The end of that copper piping is underneath the house and runs back out side behind a huge water heater so I am unable to get to it

Comment: Tried doing the new cast and it still leaks through. someone said I need to saw it off at a round spot in order for the fit to be good enough to not leak? In any case I cannot get to the other end of that copper piping as it goes underneath the house